File Explorer Crash when Accessing Folders with Shortcuts (from Network Locations)
I'm having a strange problem with a coworkers computer. To summarize, when he attempts to access a select few folders from a network location, file explorer will indefinitely hang trying to access the folder showing "Working on it..." This requires us to restart Explorer from task manager, but even this sometimes doesn't work and can require a restart. Originally he couldn't access the top level folder, and we narrowed that down to a recursive shortcut, or a shortcut pointing to the same folder it was in. However, these new folders he can't access are harder to figure out. From what I can tell, the one thing they seem to share is the folders contain a shortcut. I'm hoping somebody has experienced this problem before and may have advice. I've tried looking through Event Viewer and using ProcMon to identify any problems, but havent found anything useful. I've also tried the usual windows suspects, updates, repair fixes, sfc, dism, chkdsk, etc. but have had no luck.
Safe Mode Fix: Booting into safe mode with networking completely resolves the problem. This I find to be bizarre. Accessing these same folders from both mapped and UNC locations works flawlessly.
Specs: Brand new Windows 11 workstation.
CPU: i9-12900K - RAM: 64GB of DDR4 - GPU: RTX 3060

Is this access issue limited to a single computer and/or user account? As in, are other users on the SAME computer able to access this folder OK or not, and is this same user able to access the same folder on a DIFFERENT computer, or not?

@music2myear good question. Unfortunately, most people at our company use a single login for the file server, which works fine on other computers. I'll test creating another user on the same computer and see if the same behavior is observed, thanks! Our file server and general network setup is horrendous, but that's a topic for another post.

@music2myear I created another account on the same computer, same exact behavior. Also tried terminating every background process and service I could, but nothing changed. Probably going to reformat tomorrow as this has been plaguing us for weeks.

Such crashes are unlikely to be due to processes but more likely due to DLLs of various kinds that get loaded into Explorer (as shell extensions) or into every program (as hooks)... I'd try examining the crash logs (I think they're in Event Viewer?) for hints of a third-party .dll, maybe ProcExp to see what DLLs are loaded into all processes.

I double down on @grawity_u1686 and add.. try this tool to disable extensions.  Start with non-ms ones.  Start with obvious garbage.  As mentioned, Process Explorer is a great way to see the DLLs loaded into explorer.exe too.

@grawity_u1686 problem is, Explorer doesn't technically crash. It just hangs indefinitely trying to load the folder and usually requires a restart of the computer. I'll try and see what I can find in ProcExp, however. Thanks for the insight you both!

@jwiden-ht: In that case, try opening process properties and looking at the thread list, but still also look for unusual DLLs (Nirsoft ShExView for shell extensions).

@grawity_u1686 The "process properties" of explorer.exe in Process Explorer? And if so, any recommendations to using the "Threads" view as there is a ton of information that's constantly changing.

@grawity_u1686 I tried disabling every Shell Extension other than ones labelled "Windows® Operating System" using "ShellExView" however nothing changed. Then I tried disabling batches of the OS extensions but kept running into new problems like not being able to access network drives and file paths not working. Thanks all for the advice, but we've put enough time into this and plan to reformat.
